# Seaborn - Modify y axes by a factor in a histogram

Tags: python, histogram, seaborn

I am trying to present a histogram plot using `FacetGrid` My question is how can I divide the y-axes by a factor. For example in the data below: let's said that 
I need to normalize the y-axes, dividing site `a` by 2 and site `b` by 5.
How can I modify the y-axes and get the new values of all plots? I'll appreciate any insights

```
dfpp = pd.DataFrame({'site': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                  'lenght': [3, 4, 5, 7,4, 9,4,3,12]})

g = sns.FacetGrid(dfpp, col="site")
g = (g.map(plt.hist, "lenght",bins=3))
```

Comment: y coordinate is frequency. You can calculate frequency, and then divide by a factor.

Comment: Thanks Dejan, but I don't think is an efficient way to do it since frequency change by each plot and each time that I modify the bins. Any other suggestions?